# Is There a Mandatory Relationship Between PID and Data Length in LIN Communication Protocols?

Tags: lin

In numerous articles by IC manufacturers and measurement device makers, I've encountered references to LIN PID indicating the expected length of data bytes in the response.

```
ID Range(Dec)   Data Length
0-31             2
32-47            4
48-63            8
```

However, upon reviewing the "LIN_Specification_Package_2.2A" document, I found that this requirement is not included.

does is PID and Data length relation is mandatory one ?

Answer (score 0):

> *However, upon reviewing the "LIN_Specification_Package_2.2A" document,
> I found that this requirement is not included.*

The [document](https://www.cs-group.de/file/lin-specification-package/?wpdmdl=15783&refresh=65f2fd7a266a31710423418&ind=0&filename=LIN_Specification_Package_2.2A-2.pdf) states this: -

[image]

I think that's clear enough without being too specific (it cannot specific of course because different systems will use different data filed lengths).

For the protected identifier (PID), it is defined by the user as a means of ensuring that disparate systems cannot somehow be used together irrationally. Basically it can be thought of as a destination address i.e. it refers to a specific slave that is being asked to respond.

Comment: by this statement,  i can able to send 8 byte of data for all unconditional frames right?

Comment: A frame can carry between one and eight bytes if data. As to whether this is appropriate for the system you are designing is up to you to ensure.